# Let $v_1$ and $v_2$ be oriented vector lengths positioned tail-to-tail. Prove $t_1v_1 + t_2v_2 = v$ for some scalars $t_1, t_2$ and all vectors $v$.

Tags: vectors

> Consider two oriented lengths $v_1$ and $v_2$, tail-to-tail. (Neither is a scalar multiple of the other.) Show that every oriented length $v$ in the plane determined by $v_1$ and $v_2$ is of the form $t_1v_1 + t_2v_2$ for some scalars $t_1$ and $t_2$.

The restriction here is that the coordinates are not introduced yet, so the proof must be strictly geometric(?).

By parallelogram rule, the sum of two vectors $v_1, v_2$ is $v_1 + v_2 = v$. Do I just say that scaling $v_1, v_2$ by $t_1, t_2$ affects $v$ in one-to-one correspondence?

Comment: how do you define the plain determined by $v_1,v_2$? isnt it all their linear combinations?

Comment: What's difficult here is that the concept of "linear combinations" is not introduced yet, either. It's from Linear and Geometric Algebra by Alan Macdonald.

Comment: Then I ask again, what is the definition of that plain? why there is such plain?

Comment: I just searched the term "plane" in the book(ctrl + F) and this is(the problem at hand) is the first time the term "plane" is mentioned.